# javascript push in a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, push

When I try to push elements into a javascript array, it doesn't work.
This is the simplest sample I can come up with.
Why doesn't this work?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <script>
    var i;
    var mycars = new Array();

    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
      mycars.push[ i.toString()+"-" ];
    }

    alert(mycars.join(""));

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`push`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.7) is a function. You call functions with `()`, not `[]`:

```
mycars.push( i.toString()+"-" );
// here ---^     and here ----^
```

Where you probably got confused is that you can add to an array without using `push`, just by assigning to an array element, even if that element doesn't exist yet. So for instance, your loop could look like this:

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
  mycars[mycars.length] = i.toString()+"-";
}
```

There, because I'm referring to an array element (`mycars[mycars.length]`), not calling a function, I use `[]`.

Side note: Rather than `var mycars = new Array();`, just write `var mycars = [];`. It does the same thing but is more concise and not prone to side effects.

Comment: If I didn't know better with that kind of speed I'd say you were Jon Skeet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49685529/how-to-do-find-using-node-and-mongodb...need help