# How to do find using node and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, express

Below Data stored in my collection

```
[
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d9feff55d6b4dd1171dd9e"),"name":"John", "rank":1, "year":1998 ,"class":"a" ,"total":"1128" },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("feff553d95d6b4dd19e171dd"),"name":"Sherif", "rank":1, "year":1999 ,"class":"b" ,"total":"1163"},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("9fef53dd6b4dd1171f55dd9e"),"name":"shravan", "rank":1, "year":2000 ,"class":"b" ,"total":"1113"},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("117153d9fef6b4dddd9ef55d"),"name":"aneesh", "rank":1, "year":2001 ,"class":"d" ,"total":"1145"},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("dd9e53feff55d6b4dd1171d9"),"name":"abdul", "rank":1, "year":1997 ,"class":"a" ,"total":"1100"},
]
```

I wrote api for find and `[{ "name":"John", "rank":1, "year":1998 },{ "name":"Sherif", "rank":1, "year":1999 }]` this is the data i am getting from req.body here i mentioned as a query

```
router.post('/users',function(req,res){
  var query =[{ "name":"John", "rank":1, "year":1998 },{ "name":"Sherif", "rank":1, "year":1999 }]
  User.find(query, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.json(result)

  });
```

My expectation this res.json should return only these two documents

```
[
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53d9feff55d6b4dd1171dd9e"),"name":"John", "rank":1, "year":1998 ,"class":"a" ,"total":"1128" },
{ "_id" : ObjectId("feff553d95d6b4dd19e171dd"),"name":"Sherif", "rank":1, "year":1999 ,"class":"b" ,"total":"1163"}]
```

In mongodb we can write like this

```
db.users.find({rank:1, name:{$in:["John","Sherif"]}, year:{$in:[1998,1999]}})
```

i want solution in nodejs,express because based on request we need to do find
Help me out

Answer (score 5):

try with mongoose [`$or`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-or) operator

```
var query = {
  $or : [
    {
      "name":"John", 
      "rank":1,
      "year":1998 
    },
    {
      "name":"Sherif",
      "rank":1, "year":1999 
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your find query should will look like this:

```
db.collection.find({rank:1, name:{$in:["John","Sherif"]}, year:{$in:[1998,1999]}})
```

And the result would be:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53d9feff55d6b4dd1171dd9e"),
"name" : "John",
"rank" : 1,
"year" : 1998,
"class" : "a",
"total" : "1128"
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("feff553d95d6b4dd19e171dd"),
"name" : "Sherif",
"rank" : 1,
"year" : 1999,
"class" : "b",
"total" : "1163"
}
```

Comment: Is that the same you mentioned as your expected output?

Comment: I'm not a node.js guy, just provided the query thinking that you're struggling with the query. Please edit the question to reflect on what you need. Plus you should be able to proceed yourself once you have the query. This query is a very simpler one.

Comment: @itsme Please replace my above mentioned query with the query you have added in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Although a few people have answered, but I believe complete way to do it is:

```
router.post('/users',function(req, res, next) {
    // req.body = [{ "name":"John", "rank":1, "year":1998 },{ "name":"Sherif", "rank":1, "year":1999 }]

    // mapping users to each array
    const query = { $or: req.body };
    // execute query
    User.find(query, function(err, result) {
        if (err) next(err);
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```